# What is the solution of this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the sum of the squares of all real numbers satisfying the equation $x^{256} -256^{32} = 0$

> a) $8$
>
> b) $128$
>
> c) $512$
>
> d) $65536$

I found out that $x = 2$, but what does the question ask us to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked the sum of the real roots of the equation $x^{256}-256^{32}=0$. You have found one real root i.e. 2 . The other real root is $-2$. So the sum is $2^2+(-2)^2=4+4=8$. So the answer is (a)